# 1 responses - grammar issue - when viewing profile?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, grammar, plurals

When you click your user name and there is one response you can view the tab reads "1 responses".

Shouldn't it be "**1 response**"?

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen one of these in a while. Where's the giant "S"?

Comment: Here comes the giant **S** ... [background](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/50049)

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @animuson Both es.stackoverflow.com and pt.stackoverflow.com do this correctly. That proves this is not a "Status by design", but an actual bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The tab name is 'responses', because it's what you click to go and view your responses. The `1` is a *different UI element*, that shows the number of 'new' responses as a number. The two are next to each other, but there's no single piece of text that says "1 responses".

It's <sup><sub>warning: terrible analogy time</sub></sup> as if you had this text:

> His son is 1. Bananas are yellow.

and were complaining that "1 bananas" is pluralised incorrectly. Although the two pieces of text are *next* to each other, they aren't a *single phrase*.

This is the relevant html:

```
<a title="your recent responses" href="/users/151211/aakashm?tab=responses">
    <span class="bounty-indicator-tab">1</span>        
    responses
</a>
```

See? Different pieces of text.

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is valid there. The tag is called "responses" and the 1 flag indicates you have one response.

I seriously don't know what it bothers people, but maybe it's because I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: I really hope there is a grammar mistake in my two sentences answer, it will make my last line argument even stronger....

Comment: _"Valid there it is, I think. Indicates you have one response, the flag does. A native English speaker, I am not."_

Comment: @yoda. You probably forgot the source: _"Valid there it is, I think. Indicates you have one response, the flag does. A native English speaker, I am not."_ **(William Shakespeare)**

Comment: — Michael Scott @gdo